# How to incress position of a pointer that is pointing to a char array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I have these functions:

```
void mon_strlen(char *s){
    printf("Contenue: %c\n",*s);
    s++; //here
    printf("Contenue: %c\n",*s);
    system("PAUSE");
}

int main()
{
    char str[10]="Hello";
    char *s;
    s=str[0];
    mon_strlen(&s);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

How can I incrase the position of memory of pointer `s` in the function `mon_strlen` to print:

```
Contenue: H
Contenue: e
```

or my logic is wrong?

Comment: This wouldn't compile with warnings.

Comment: Change `mon_strlen(char *s)` to `mon_strlen(char **s)` and inside that function, change `s++` to `(*s)++`.

Comment: @barakmanos probably or look at **Sourav**'s answer.

Comment: @iharob: Yep, didn't notice that answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, change

```
    s=str[0];
```

to

```
    s=str;
```

or

```
    s=&str[0];
```

and call `mon_strlen()` as

```
mon_strlen(s);
```

Comment: I didn't notice that, why don't people use warnings? well done.

Comment: @iharob Right you are, after all warnings are there for a reason. Someone (or a lot of people, actually) would not have devoted his/her (their) (professional) life to make the compiler emit the warnings if they were supposed to be ___ignored___.

Answer (score 0):

To make the changes available in `main()` you need to pass a pointer to the pointer like this

```
void mon_strlen(char **s) {
    char *ptr;
    if (s == NULL)
        return;
    ptr = *s;
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return;
    printf("Contenue: %c\n", *ptr);
    ptr = (*s)++; //here
    printf("Contenue: %c\n", *ptr);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

your call in `main()` is as if your `mon_strlen()` function had this signature

```
void mon_strlen(char **s)
```

which your compiler would have warned you about if you enable warnings.

And in `main()` you need to pass `str` like this

```
mon_strlen(&str);
```